# How hold the splash screen till data are ready

Tags: android, flutter

Is it possible that the spash screen (launch screen) 
is shown till the data needed for the app is ready?

Are there other options in manifest.xml as below?
"io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"

Comment: You can use `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` for such things. And show loader or splash until data loaded

Answer (score 1):

After many retries I found a solution which could be optimized.
Please tell me your opinion

Normally flutter starts with

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
```

I inserted the data acquisition on the begin by modifying the code

```
void main() async {

  final OrderedAppList aList = new OrderedAppList(); //class to get all data

  var funx = (int) async => aList.getit(); //to get all of the data

    var value;
    value = await funx(1); //should wait for the return value

  runApp(new MyApp(
      qallUserApps: aList.allUserApps,
      qlistLen: value, // means aList.listLen,
      qplatformVersion: aList.platformVersion,
      qmodel: aList.model
  ));
  }
```

And in MyApp:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List qallUserApps;
  final int qlistLen;
  final String qplatformVersion;
  final String qmodel;

  // Constructor:
  const MyApp({Key key, this.qallUserApps,
                        this.qlistLen,
                        this.qplatformVersion,
                        this.qmodel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// ...
}
```

Code part of the class OrderedAppList:

```
class OrderedAppList {
  int listLen= -1;
  String platformVersion = "Unknown Platform";
  String model = "Unknown Platform";
  List allUserApps = null;


  Future<int> getit() async {
    try {
      allUserApps = await AppsAsStateless.allApps;
      listLen = allUserApps.length;
    } on Exception {
      allUserApps = null;
      listLen = 0;
    }
// ...
return listLen ;
}
```

Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

it works fine and
the code in main can be optimized:

```
void main() async { // async that data acquisition done before any widgets shown

  final OrderedAppList aList = new OrderedAppList();

  int value;
  value = await aList.getit();

  runApp(new MyApp(
      qallUserApps: aList.allUserApps,
      qlistLen: value, // = aList.listLen,
      qplatformVersion: aList.platformVersion,
      qmodel: aList.model
  ));
}
```